# SQL Procedure with OUTPUT Parameter

Tags: function, t-sql, stored-procedures

Create a stored procedure called dbo.CreateFamilyMember to create a new person in the database.
The procedure should take the following parameters:

• SIN

• FirstName

• LastName

• FatherSIN

• MotherSIN

• DateOfBirth

• DateOfDeath

• NetWorth

• PersonID

The parameters for date of birth and date of death should both be optional. When not provided, they should default
to NULL. The parameter person ID should be an output parameter that returns the newly created ID. The NetWorth
should default to 10000.

All parameters should have datatype that are appropriate for their intended use. Similarly, any variables used should
have data types that are appropriate for their intended use.
The MotherPersonID and FatherPersonID for the new person should be found using their respective SIN. If the SIN is
not found in the database a new record should be created for that person. Note that it is possible that one parent is
already in the database and the other not.

The creation of the new person, along with any parents that might need to be created, should be one atomic
operation. If any insert fails, all should be rolled back.

The Person ID for the new person should be returned using the Person ID parameter.

The correct solution will get the person ID for all newly inserted records by retrieving the last identity created. Only
partial marks will be awarded if you look up the new ID by SIN and/or name. This only applies to lookups following
an insert (i.e. per the requirements, it is acceptable to do your initial parent lookup by SIN).

I have written a procedure but I don't think I am doing it correctly. Could someone please let me know if I have done something wrong.

This is the database:

```
USE FamilyHeritage;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (
    PersonID       INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    SIN            CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    FatherPersonID INT NULL,
    MotherPersonID INT NULL,    
    FirstName      NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    LastName       NVARCHAR(60) NULL,
    DateOfBirth    DATE NULL,
    DateOfDeath    DATE NULL,
    NetWorth       MONEY,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( PersonID ),
    CONSTRAINT AK_Person_SIN UNIQUE ( SIN )
);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person ON;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Person ( PersonID, SIN, FatherPersonID, MotherPersonID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateOfDeath, NetWorth)
VALUES -- GENERATION 1
       (  1, '112940116', NULL, NULL, 'Harry',   'Martin',   '1912-02-16', '1963-04-15', NULL),
       (  2, '112940213', NULL, NULL, 'Marie',   'LeFleur',  '1916-04-13', '1963-04-15' , NULL),
       (  3, '112940321', NULL, NULL, 'Ron',     'Jones',    '1917-05-21', '2002-11-30' , NULL),
       (  4, '112940426', NULL, NULL, 'Sarah',   'Kim',      '1917-03-26', '2006-10-09', NULL ),
       (  5, '112940522', NULL, NULL, 'Fred',    'Cooper',   '1915-11-22', '2000-12-11' , NULL),
       (  6, '112940630', NULL, NULL, 'Audrey',  'Maclean',  '1920-06-30', '2007-03-31' , NULL),
       (  7, '112940721', NULL, NULL, 'Leo',     'Sanchez',  '1916-08-21', '2004-02-29' , NULL),
       (  8, '112940804', NULL, NULL, 'Sarah',   'Black',    '1917-08-04', '2005-08-07' , NULL),
       (  9, '112940912', NULL, NULL, 'Hui',     'Peng',     '1919-11-12', '1971-06-15' , NULL),
       ( 10, '112941002', NULL, NULL, 'Rita',    'Yang',     '1921-08-02', '1990-12-03' , NULL),
       ( 11, '112941109', NULL, NULL, 'Jerry',   'Gold',     '1919-07-09', '1998-05-04' , NULL),
       ( 12, '112941106', NULL, NULL, 'Kate',    'Lyall',    '1920-04-06', NULL , 2000000),
                                    
       -- GENERATION 2              
       ( 13, '321650142',    1,    2, 'Peter',   'Martin',   '1942-01-02', NULL, 1800000 ),
       ( 14, '321650241',    3,    4, 'Erin',    'Jones',    '1941-02-14', '1968-07-02', 1200000 ),
       ( 15, '321650340',    5,    6, 'Ben',     'Cooper',   '1940-10-31', '2017-09-21' , NULL),
       ( 16, '321650444',    7,    8, 'Tina',    'Sanchez',  '1944-12-25', NULL , 1100000),
       ( 17, '321650541',    9,   10, 'Jeff',    'Peng',     '1941-09-23', '2018-02-12', 1300000 ),
       ( 18, '321650643',    11,  12, 'Anne',    'Gold',     '1943-01-17', NULL, 1600000 ),
                                    
       -- GENERATION 3              
       ( 19, '407580107',   13,   14, 'Ari',     'Martin',   '1968-07-02', NULL, 700000 ),
       ( 20, '407580211',   15,   16, 'Judy',    'Cooper',   '1970-11-11', NULL , 700000),
       ( 21, '407580310',   15,   16, 'Daniel',  'Cooper',   '1968-10-04', NULL, 900000 ),
       ( 22, '407580403',   17,   18, 'Kate',    'Peng',     '1969-03-07', NULL, 200000 ),
                                    
       -- GENERATION 4              
       ( 23, '511550100',   19,   20, 'Devon',   'Martin',   '1993-07-11', NULL , 40000), 
       ( 24, '511550201',   19,   20, 'Jillian', 'Martin',   '1996-05-15', NULL , 70000), 
       ( 25, '511550399',   19,   20, 'Brie',    'Martin',   '1998-01-19', NULL , 90000), 
       ( 26, '511550499',   21,   22, 'Stan',    'Cooper',   '1994-05-21', NULL, 90000 ), 
       ( 27, '511550505',   21,   22, 'Ian',     'Cooper',   '1997-08-25', NULL , 250000);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Person OFF;
GO
```

This is my dbo.GetPersonID Function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetPersonID (
        @SIN CHAR(9)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN;
        DECLARE @ID INT;

        SELECT @ID = PersonID
        FROM dbo.Person
        WHERE SIN = @SIN;

        RETURN @ID;
END;
GO
```

And this is my procedure in question:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateFamilyMember (
    @SIN            CHAR(9),
    @FirstName      NVARCHAR(50),
    @LastName       NVARCHAR(60),
    @FatherSIN      CHAR(9),
    @MotherSIN      CHAR(9),
    @DateOfBirth    DATE = NULL,
    @DateOfDeath    DATE = NULL,
    @NetWorth       MONEY = 10000,
    @PersonID       INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN;
        
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @FatherPersonID INT;
        SELECT @FatherPersonID = dbo.GetPersonID (@FatherSIN)
            IF(@FatherPersonID IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.Person
                VALUES (@FatherSIN, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

            END

            DECLARE @MotherPersonID INT;
            SELECT @MotherPersonID = dbo.GetPersonID (@MotherSIN)
                IF(@MotherPersonID IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO dbo.Person
                    VALUES (@MotherSIN, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

                END

            INSERT INTO dbo.Person
            VALUES (@SIN, @FatherPersonID, @MotherPersonID, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @DateOfDeath, @NetWorth)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

END;
GO


/**** Requirement 3 ******/
DECLARE @ID INT;
EXEC dbo.CreateFamilyMember '643138677', 'Gary', 'Martin', '501550100', '503561001', '2019-12-10','', '', @ID OUTPUT;
SELECT @ID;
```

Comment: Best practice: You should add a _column list_ to your `insert` statements to ensure that the supplied values go to the correct columns. Interesting things can happen when you assume the order of the columns and the table is subsequently altered.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) when inserting the new person dataset.

You can do this by creating a table variable

```
DECLARE @NewID TABLE (PersID INT)
```

Output the PersonID of the inserted person to the table variable

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
OUTPUT inserted.PersonID INTO @NewID
VALUES (@SIN, @FatherPersonID, @MotherPersonID, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @DateOfDeath, @NetWorth)
```

Set the output parameter of your procedure to the new id value

```
SET @PersonID = (SELECT PersID FROM @NewID)
```

Additionaly: In your current procedure version you insert **NULL** for the father/mother personId if those were created newly.

See also https://dbfiddle.uk/KCkI1lsB